# How to automatically check for new data in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets

My apologies in advance; upon researching this I have found ample resources though, as I'm not familiar with programming, stitching it into my code has been challenging. I figured I'd ask the experts for a quick opinion!

I am pulling data from Google Sheets onto my website using JSON. However, if I change the Google Sheets data, the JSON does not automatically update unless I refresh the page. I want to make live, "real-time" data that will update on my site without refreshing the page.

Google Sheets publishes updates every 5 minutes, which is "live enough" for my needs. How can I make the below JSON script check for new data every 5 minutes? Thanks a lot in advance.

````
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
function BuildChart(labels, values, chartTitle) {
    var data = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: chartTitle, // Name the series
            data: values,
            backgroundColor: ['rgb(54, 162, 225)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
            ],
        }],
    };

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: {
            responsive: true, // Instruct chart js to respond nicely.
            maintainAspectRatio: false, // Add to prevent default behaviour of full-width/height 
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                        scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Your Account'
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: ''
                    }
                }]
            },
        }
    });

    return myChart;
}


var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var json = JSON.parse(this.response);
      console.log(json);

// Map json labels  back to values array
var labels = json.feed.entry.map(function (e) {
  return e.gsx$twitter.$t;
});

// Map json values back to values array
var values = json.feed.entry.map(function (e) {
    return e.gsx$followers.$t;e.gsx$followers2
});

BuildChart(labels, values, "Followers");
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DC1eO0s6haFI59HNeNEL27T4tDVYIBfYGxzp882xjDo/od6/public/full?alt=json", false);
  xhttp.send();
    </script>```
````

Comment: You can poll your sheet by wrapping your `xhttp` (Ajax) code in a function. Then have that function get called every X milliseconds with `setTimeout`. You will likely need to destroy your old chart before adding the updated one.

Comment: @hungerstar, you are right but I'm having trouble implementing this. My programming skills are lacking, to say the least. Will keep digging, thanks again!

Comment: @Heretic Monkey - yes it does, but implementation is another story (I know this must look so simple for you, but I'm unfamiliar with programming). Will keep trying to implement something, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your code every 5 min, you can embed it into a function, and then call this function every 5 minutes with for example

```
function startPolling(){setInterval(refreshData,5*60*1000);};
```

and you can activate your polling function with an `onClick` event.

**Sample:**

```
<div id="msg"></div><input type="button" value="Start Polling" onClick="startPolling();" />
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
function startPolling(){setInterval(refreshData,5*60*1000);}
function refreshData(){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var json = JSON.parse(this.response);
      console.log(json);

// Map json labels  back to values array
var labels = json.feed.entry.map(function (e) {
  return e.gsx$twitter.$t;
});

// Map json values back to values array
var values = json.feed.entry.map(function (e) {
    return e.gsx$followers.$t;e.gsx$followers2
});

BuildChart(labels, values, "Followers");
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1DC1eO0s6haFI59HNeNEL27T4tDVYIBfYGxzp882xjDo/od6/public/full?alt=json", false);
  xhttp.send();
}
function BuildChart(labels, values, chartTitle) {
    var data = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: chartTitle, // Name the series
            data: values,
            backgroundColor: ['rgb(54, 162, 225)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
            ],
        }],
    };

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: {
            responsive: true, // Instruct chart js to respond nicely.
            maintainAspectRatio: false, // Add to prevent default behaviour of full-width/height 
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                        scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Your Account'
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: ''
                    }
                }]
            },
        }
    });

    return myChart;
}

    </script>
```